# Saving file as a different name

Tags: java, file, save

I have a Java form in which you can select a file to open. I have that file:

```
File my_file = ...
```

I want to be able to save my file as a different name.
how can I do it using "File my_file"?

I tried:

```
File current_file = JPanel_VisualizationLogTab.get_File();
String current_file_name = current_file.getName();
//String current_file_extension = current_file_name.substring(current_file_name.lastIndexOf('.'), current_file_name.length()).toLowerCase();
FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(new Frame(), "Save", FileDialog.SAVE);
fileDialog.setFile(current_file_name);
fileDialog.setVisible(true);
```

But that doesn't save the file.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using the `Apache Commons IO` library to make this task easier.  With this library, you could use the handy `FileUtils` class that provides many helper functions for handling file IO.  I think you would be interested in the `copy(File file, File file)` function

```
try{
    File current_file = JPanel_VisualizationLogTab.get_File();
    File newFile = new File("new_file.txt");
    FileUtils.copyFile(current_file, newFile);
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[Documentation](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to copy it with a different name, i found this piece of Code via google

```
public static void copyFile(File in, File out) throws IOException {
    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(in).getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(out).getChannel();
    try {
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (inChannel != null)
            inChannel.close();
        if (outChannel != null)
            outChannel.close();
    }
}
```

now you can call it with

```
    File inF = new File("/home/user/inputFile.txt");
    File outF = new File("/home/user/outputFile.txt");
    copyFile(inF, outF);
```

it´s just important that both Files exist, otherswise it will raise an exception

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the file name.
Use:

```
myfile.renameTo("neeFile")
```

Comment: This would only make sense, if you would want to rename the file and is useless, if you would like to have another copy of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Method called `renameTo(new File("whatever you want"));` for File Objects

Comment: I need to keep the current file and just make a copy of the current file with a different name..